# exploit Dropbox file redundancy check

Tags: hash, md5, crc, dropbox

in Dropbox if a file is already present at their servers, the file is not uploaded. It syncs instantly..

Now, this check is done on a few things i think, probably the file size, file name, and of course the CRC (md5 hash or something...)

I was thinking.. if I know the file name, its size and its CRC, is it possible to create a fake file that produces that particular CRC (reverse hashing) so that dropbox actually syncs the true file?

It's just an experiment, it could be done for example with linux distribution images..
any idea on the topic?

Comment: Yes, this is possible. No reverse hashing is needed, you can add files to your account with just the list of hashes: https://github.com/laanwj/dropship

Comment: For documentation purpose: http://thehackernews.com/2011/05/dropbox-potential-security-flaw.html

3 known attacks targeting dropbox: http://www.networkworld.com/news/2011/081711-dropbox-249830.html

claim of fixing these issues:
http://www.macworld.co.uk/macsoftware/news/?newsid=3297796

Description of fix:
https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=2483338

Answer (score 2):

Curious to see that someone is thinking about this also.

Problem 1:
Even if you were able to  create a fake file with the same CRC, the client would just not upload the file again (but you would still keep your fake file in your computer).
You would just receive the desired file on the other computers associated with your dropbox account.

Problem 2:
Creating that fake file seems a bit impossible from my point of view. CRC's were developed to check file integrity so it seems a bit complex to create a file with the same CRC without a massive brute-force.

MY SUGGESTION:
I believe it would be much easier to modify the CRC routines in the Dropbox source code (if you have it) and allow the injection of your fake CRC values.

Final comment: I might not be very creative but I do not find a legal reason for the use of this scheme. Dropbox already provides a Public folder to share files (but traffic limits apply).